# Using ABS function withing Countifs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I am able to use the ABS function on this formula somehow!

`=SUM(COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!A$2:A$191,{"0*","1*","2*","3*","4*","5*","6*","7*","8*","9*"},'Sheet1'!E$2:E$191,">"&F8))`

**I tried the following but it is not working:**

`=SUM(COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!A$2:A$191,{"0*","1*","2*","3*","4*","5*","6*","7*","8*","9*"},**ABS('Sheet1'!E$2:E$191)**,">"&F8))`

Is there something I am missing here? Tried all sorts of strategies around it and I am not able to do it. Please help.

Comment: Will be good to see some sample data and description as to what your aim is.

Comment: It might be useful if you could share with us what you mean by ***not working***.  And also, please read the Help topic for  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and edit your question in order to help someone reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated COUNTIFS does not allow the manipulation of the data, in this case we can simply add another array using an IF in the COUNTIFS:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!A$2:A$191,{"0*","1*","2*","3*","4*","5*","6*","7*","8*","9*"},'Sheet1'!E$2:E$191,IF({1;0},">"&F8,"<" & -1 * F8)))
```

Comment: @ForwardEd yes, we do.

Comment: Thanks Scott!! Works perfectly :)))) Do you mind explaining this bit so that I learn: IF({1;2},">"&F8,"<" & -1 * F8

Comment: Actually I take that back, it is not giving accurate answers. This instead worked accurately: =SUM(COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!A$2:A$191,{"0*","1*","2*","3*","4*","5*","6*","7*","8*","9*"},'Sheet1'!E$2:E$191,{">";"<-"}&F8))

Comment: @Eyale Please post that as an answer.  Sorry mine did not work

Comment: @Eyale also I fixed mine, I forgot that `0` is false not `2`.  Is should work now.

Comment: Ah ok. That fixed it :)))

Answer (score 0):

**Both these worked in case anybody wants to refer to them:**

=SUM(COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!A$2:A$191,{"0*","1*","2*","3*","4*","5*","6*","7*","8*","9*"},'Sheet1'!E$2:E$191,{">";"<-"}&F8))

**AND**

=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS('Sheet1'!A$2:A$191,{"0*","1*","2*","3*","4*","5*","6*","7*","8*","9*"},'Sheet1'!E$2:E$191,IF({1;0},">"&F8,"<" & -1 * F8)))